# Should I use proxy while dealing with other domains?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, proxy, file-get-contents

I see resources that mention using proxies in scraping websites, I have been using pure PHP and some PHP libraries for a while.

So for example:

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```

Or using CURL:

```
$url = "http://example.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

For a while I didn't face serious issues, Just sometimes I get some errors from `file_get_contents`, But after that it works without doing anything.

Should I use proxy while doing that?

If so, How could I get a proxy?

Comment: Try: https://www.php-proxy.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well honestly proxies are all right but I made an AliExpress-**scraper** but it needed VPN because with proxy I was still been blocked and I had to change it all the time. VPN is better option there are some free VPNs [here](https://www.trusted-vpn.com/mp/hackers-data-theft-warning-letters-vpn-protects-you/?price=no&design=table&category=y&popup=y&bandage=y&source=gs&adw-cpn=free-c&c=0002&gclid=CjwKCAjwqarbBRBtEiwArlfEIBGYgamA5ZuadtbLJHN7y-qbRhy6TFGgvZT-vuDnp5GC33GmgnvLCxoC75UQAvD_BwE)

Comment: I have been doing that for a while and I haven't used vpn or proxy, But it didn't stop working

Comment: I think is the traffic  try it out with proxy first if you get blocked use VPN but for sure don't use your own network, it's not dangerous but you will be feeling bad and anxious if they block  you :)